# What's "parenthesis type" as in (type v) in a definition or in a function signature?

Tags: generics, types, ocaml

I know generic types, but sometimes I see `let a (type v w) etc.` in code, what's the difference?

Comment: See if you can find anything useful in the [GADT](https://cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2019sp/textbook/) section of the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are locally abstract types. See https://ocaml.org/manual/locallyabstract.html. They are useful for:

- creating local modules

```
let sort_and_deduplicate (type a) compare l =
  let module S = Set.Make(struct type t = a let compare = compare end) in
  S.elements (S.of_list l)
```

- refining types on pattern matching in presence of GADT

```
type _ monoid = Int: int monoid | Float: float monoid
let zero (type a) (m:a monoid): a =  match m with
| Int -> 0
| Float -> 0.
```

- debugging polymorphic functions

```
let wrong_id (type a) (x:a) = x + 1
```

```
Error: This expression has type a but an expression was expected of type int
```